# What causes 'The provided key element does not match the schema' error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

Thanks a lot.

I'm using glue for migrating one dynamodb table to another table in the same region.
However I've got this error.

> An error occurred while calling o97.pyWriteDynamicFrame. The provided
> key element does not match the schema (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2;
> Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID:
> O7T8OP9M14IGOQFL9HOJP; Proxy: null)

The source dynamodb table items are simply like this.

```
{
  "Item": {
    "memNo": {
      "S": "b"
    }
  }
}
{
  "Item": {
    "memNo": {
      "S": "a"
    }
  }
}
{
  "Item": {
    "memNo": {
      "S": "cde"
    }
  }
}
```

And both source and target table have just one partition key.

```
memNo (String)
```

and I turned on PITR option for source table, and exported to S3 bucket.
so the source data is now .gz file.

And this is the Glue code

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

# Script generated for node Data Catalog table
DataCatalogtable_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="dynamotest",
    table_name="w5dllnzmzq7kdhj5oo4epg476a_json_gz",
    transformation_ctx="DataCatalogtable_node1",
)

# Script generated for node Apply Mapping
ApplyMapping_node1644253291017 = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame=DataCatalogtable_node1,
    mappings=[("item.memNo.S", "string", "memNo", "string")],
    transformation_ctx="ApplyMapping_node1644253291017",
)

glueContext.write_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    frame=DataCatalogtable_node1,
    connection_type="dynamodb",
    connection_options={
        "dynamodb.output.tableName": "TargetTable"
    }
)

job.commit()
```

Whenever I try, Glue job says 'The provided key element does not match the schema' error.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that mapping function is not attached to writing function.

```
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    frame=DataCatalogtable_node1,
```

above block should be below

```
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    frame= ApplyMapping_node1644253291017,
```